# Find regular expression in regular expression (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm writing a script that returns whether or not a DNA sequence (with ambiguous letters) contains a certain subsequence (also with ambiguous letters).

I've tried creating a regular expression for both the sequence and the subsequence, but I haven't found a way to find if the latter occurs in the former. I need something like `re.search(substring,sequence)`
but where `sequence` is another regular expression instead of a string.

Does such a thing exist?

Edit: what I've tried:

```
import re

def subseqof(substr,sequence):
    substr_exp = ''
    sequence_exp = ''
    for letter in substr:
        for code,expr in zip(['A','C','G','T','R','Y','S','W','K','M','B','D','H','V','N','X'],
                           ['A','C','G','T','[AG]','[CT]','[GC]','[AT]','[GT]','[AC]','[CGT]','[AGT]','[ACT]','[ACG]','[ACGT]','[ACGT]']):
            if letter == code:
                substr_exp += expr
    for letter in sequence:
        for code,expr in zip(['A','C','G','T','R','Y','S','W','K','M','B','D','H','V','N','X'],
                           ['A','C','G','T','[AG]','[CT]','[GC]','[AT]','[GT]','[AC]','[CGT]','[AGT]','[ACT]','[ACG]','[ACGT]','[ACGT]']):
            if letter == code:
                sequence_exp += expr
    if re.search(substr_exp,sequence_exp) != None:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: @moogle edited.

Comment: Why not store a successful match against the first sequence as a new string to check later with your other sequence? I'm not recommending that structure of coding, but it seems like it would at least unblock you for now.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck I'm not sure what you mean by 'successful match against the first sequence'. I need to know if any unambiguous substring defined by the regex `substring_exp` occurs in any of the sequences defined by `sequence_exp`.

Comment: 1. Do your first regex. If match, store that _match_in a variable. 2. Run second regex against that match's variable.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck But what do I do the first regex on?

Comment: First the sequence, then the sub-sequence.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck But the regex would never find a match since an `'R'`in the string would never be found to match an `'[AG]'` in the regex, although that letter does represent those 2 nucleotides. Have I completely lost the plot?

Comment: Maybe I have. Your question makes no sense as-written with my input not being sufficient. The way you explain it, you have a string to check like "I am a special string." Then you have a regex that tries to locate _that_ string. The regex when finding the string then tries to look for a sub-string, and successfully matches against "special" as final verification. That's the generic gist of what you conveyed, but it doesn't seem to be the case of what you need. Please be more specific.

Comment: I understand your requirement as *search for some pattern and get all matches inside other matches*. Could you please provide a minimal example: sample input text, 2 patterns you need to search for and expected result? I suspect a mere *capturing* may suffice here.

Answer (score 0):

> I need something like `re.search(substring,sequence)`
>   but where `sequence` is another regular expression instead of a string.

If I understand correctly, you want e. g. `subseqof(substr='RR', sequence='...AA...')` as well as `subseqof(substr='AA', sequence='...RR...')` to `return True` (where in both cases `R` is replaced with `[AG]`).

> Does such a thing exist?

Such a symmetric or commutative regular expression function doesn't exist. But as only a small subset of regex functionality is used here, we can easily write a proper function:

```
iupac = dict(zip(['A','C','G','T', 'R', 'Y', 'S', 'W', 'K', 'M',  'B',  'D',  'H',  'V',   'N',   'X'],
                 ['A','C','G','T','AG','CT','GC','AT','GT','AC','CGT','AGT','ACT','ACG','ACGT','ACGT']))

def subseqof(substr, sequence):
    substr_exp   = list(map(iupac.get, substr))   # list of letters represented
    sequence_exp = list(map(iupac.get, sequence)) # list of letters represented
    for start in range(len(sequence_exp)-len(substr_exp)+1):    # sequence loop
        for subpos, sub in enumerate(substr_exp):           # sub-sequence loop
            if not sequence_exp[start+subpos]: break    # if letter not in dict
            if not re.search('['+sub+']', sequence_exp[start+subpos]): break
        else: return start                          # whole subsequence matched
```